# Select column names into substitution variable

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Ideally, I would like to dynamically define a (substitution) variable in Oracle SQL. The following obviously does not work since the substitution variable is just replaced literally in the "insert into..." statement.

```
define colnames = '(select column_name from USER_TAB_COLS where table_name = B)';
insert into A(&colnames) select &colnames from B;
```

Is there a way to do something similar? perhaps in PL/SQL?

**EDIT :** I am working in SQL Developer, not in SQL*PLUS.

Comment: A substitution variable can only contain a simple text or numeric value. You could use [`listagg`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/LISTAGG.html) to generate a comma-separated list, though. Would that do?

Answer (score 1):

You will need `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` for this. Refer to https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/dynamic.htm#LNPLS01115
for more detailed usage, but in your case it will be

`EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'insert into a(:cols) select :cols from B' USING colnames, colnames;`

Comment: I am almost there: 

declare a varchar2(32767);
begin
  a:= 'select column_name from USER_TAB_COLS where table_name = B;';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'insert into A(:x) select :x from B;' USING a, a;
end;
But I get the error  "missing SELECT keyword"

Comment: That won't work. Bind variables are for data values, not structural sections of code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do, but if you want a comma-separated column list in a SQL*Plus substitution variable, here's how:

```
col column_list new_value column_list

select listagg(lower(column_name), ',') within group (order by column_id) as column_list
from   user_tab_columns
where  table_name = 'DEPARTMENTS';

COLUMN_LIST
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
department_id,department_name,manager_id,location_id

prompt insert into table_a (&column_list) ...
```

Output is:

```
insert into table_a (department_id,department_name,manager_id,location_id) ...
```

Comment: Seems to work but at the prompt, however, I get a msgbox asking to provide values for &columnlist; maybe something like a double "&" is needed to make the value persistent?

Comment: Are you sure you are running it as a script (F5) and not the normal "Run Statement" (Ctrl-Enter)? (I have added the SQL Developer tag to your question. I’m not especially familiar with it myself.)

Answer (score 0):

I guess `exec` is what you need. For example:

```
SQL> var v_empno number
SQL> exec select max(empno) into :v_empno from emp where deptno = 10;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print v_empno

   V_EMPNO
----------
      7934

SQL> select ename, job, sal
  2  from emp
  3  where empno = :v_empno;

ENAME      JOB              SAL
---------- --------- ----------
MILLER     CLERK           1300

SQL>
```

Comment: The variable is supposed to include a list of values, if I am not mistaken "select x into y" only allows for a single value. Am I wrong?

Comment: You are right. That's what SQL*Plus offers - what I thought you use, seeing code you posted. If that's not what you want, you'll have to switch to PL/SQL and use dynamic SQL (`execute immediate`).